# Angularjs - Can't update model from childs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

If got a dynamic ng-repeat for an form, a button to add new items to the lis, one button to remove items and one button to save all. I can add new items and remove them. On the save button, I pass the model "somedata", to the save method. But in the "somedata"-object, it still contains the removed items? Did I forgot something?

Thanks in advance

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in items track by $index">
     <input ng-model="somedata[foo][$index]">
     <input ng-model="somedata[bar][$index]">
     <button ng-click="removeItem($index)">remove</button>
  </li>
</ul>

<button ng-click="addItem()">add</button>
<button ng-click="saveInputs(somedata)">remove</button>

****

$scope.removeItem = function(id) {
   $scope.items.splice(id, 1);
}

$scope.saveInput = function(input) {
   console.log(input) # -> contains also deleted data???
}
```

*** SOLUTION ***
I also need to remove the item from the model

```
$scope.removeItem = function(id) {
   $scope.items.splice(id, 1);
   $scope.somedata.splice(id, 1);
};
```

Comment: Can you give more details about the code, say, what is somedata? My guess is that you should also need to remove element from somedata.

Comment: This is just a simplified code. Somedata is just a dummy-name and it is an array of objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I apologize that I cannot ask for clarification due to my lack of 50 reputation so if this answer is shoddy then I ask for your forgiveness.

It looks like you're wondering why removing the item using your button doesn't remove the element you are printing in the console. The reason for this is because you never actually touch the `somedata` object when you remove from your items list.

I have appended a plunk with my understanding of your problem.

http://plnkr.co/edit/L0EZd6IBttnTkKWepDiK?p=preview

```
$scope.removeItem = function(id) {
    $scope.items.splice(id, 1);
};
```

The snippet outlined manages the items collection but doesn't map (at least from what I can gather here) to your `somedata` collection.

I would propose this to resolve the issue or something of this nature:

```
$scope.removeItem = function(id) {
   $scope.items.splice(id, 1);
   $scope.somedata.splice(id, 1);
};
```

Comment: Any reason for the -1?